# Secure authentication structure in a React Webapp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-context

I am currently learning React and worked through some courses but still haven't completely understood how to create a proper structure for a secure web app.

For the sign in, sign up flow I use the firebase SDK. Once logged in, a user gets redirected to a private route. Right now I only have 2 user roles. Guests and signed in Users. This enables me to create private routes by using an inbuild firebase function. This is the first problem as it is not scalable once I add different roles as it would force me to send a request to the backend to check what role the user is and thus which pages he can acces.

```
if (firebase.auth().currentUser === null) {
        console.log("not logged in")
        return     (<Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/signin",
              state: {
                from: props.location
              }
            }}
          />);

    }
```

So I thought that the easiest option would be to use Context, which did work. Once a user loggs in, the server sends a user object which the app refers to for the rest of the session. I followed a bunch of tutorials and they all had the same problem that when using chrome developer tools with the react features, you could just edit the state of the user and bypass the private routes etc.

Second Try:

```
<UserContext.Consumer>{(context)=>{
          const {isLoggedIn} = context
          return(
        <Route
          {...rest}
          render={props => {

        if (isLoggedIn) {
            console.log("not logged in")
            return     (<Redirect
                to={{
                  pathname: "/signin",
                  state: {
                    from: props.location
                  }
                }}
              />);
```

I'd be grateful if somebody could point me in a direction as it seems like I am missing something important.

EDIT 1: Or is it simply that once you build the app, you can no longer access these states and it's considered safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when using chrome developer tools with the react features, you could just edit the state of the user and bypass the private routes

Your routes will never be truly private. They are part of the JavaScript bundle that gets downloaded and rendered by the browser, so they should never contain anything secret. Anyone could read this code if they really wanted to.

Consider this:

```js
if (loggedIn) {
  return <div>Secret data: ABC</div>;
}
```

The string "ABC" is contained in your app build, and is not really a secret anymore. The average user wouldn't know how to obtain it, but a developer probably would, for example by toggling some state in the developer console.

However, the data that comes from Firestore (or any another backend service) should be properly protected. Permission checks are done *server-side* before this data is sent to the browser. So, unless the user has the required permissions, the data will never be exposed to the wrong person, even if someone tampers with your client-side code in the developer console.

```js
if (loggedIn) {
  fetchDataFromBackend();
}
```

It doesn't matter if someone changes `loggedIn` to `true` so that `fetchDataFromBackend()` is called; the server will make sure the data isn't returned unless the user has the proper permission (e.g. is logged in). In the case of Firebase (Firestore), this protection is achieved with Security Rules.

And, by the way, [the recommended way to get the current user with Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) is to add a listener to the Auth object:

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

You could put this in a top-level component and share the `user` object with child components through a context. That way you don't have to call `firebase.auth()` all over the place. Here's a good starting point if you need some inspiration: https://usehooks.com/useAuth/

Comment: You're right about that the whole app gets downloaded, I think that was the missing piece for me. Thanks for your answer and the link!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are doing on the frontend site is good, but you would also need logic in the backend to protect your routes. This means that an user may be able to circumvent your route protection via dev tools on the frontend, but your backend would only send error messages to him, as it recognizes that he has no allowance.

You could do this with Higher Order Functions like this one:

```
const authenticationWrapper = createResolver(
  async ( models, session, SALT ) => {
    try {
      if (!session) {
        throw new Error("No valid credentials!");
      }

      const { id } = verify(session.token, salt);

      const valid = databasecall //

      if (!valid) {
        throw new Error("No valid user!");
      }

      return true
    } catch (error) {
      session.destroy((err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
        }
      });
    }
  }
);
```

All private backend functions would be wrapped into and authentication of the user would be checked every time.

The principle to check in Front- and Backend is called dual authentication. You can read more about it [here](http://I%20think%20what%20you%20are%20doing%20on%20the%20frontend%20site%20is%20good,%20but%20you%20would%20also%20need%20logic%20in%20the%20backend%20to%20protect%20your%20routes.%20Meaning%20that%20an%20user%20may%20be%20able%20to%20circumvent%20your%20route%20protection%20via%20dev%20tools,%20but%20your%20backend%20would%20only%20send%20error%20messages%20to%20him,%20as%20it%20recognizes%20that%20he%20has%20no%20allowance.%20This%20is%20called%20dual%20authentication.%20You%20can%20read%20more%20about%20it%20here.).